# Can anyone explain what it is that I am doing wrong here in this VLOOKUP?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When you highlight cell H4, you clearly see a lookup error, saying that it did not find 'Beanie Cap' in the results of the lookup evaluation (even thought it is clearly there in the range provided within the "Inventory" sheet).  Also, you'll notice that the lookups that DID succeed are both returning invalid "cost", "unit cost" and "shipping" values.  They appear to just be returning whatever the last lookup value was.

Here is a link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HrL9CSUgsRtgWvEkrXAyMa57fQ7EjXLda29r464Az0o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Vlookups need to contain False to specify an exact lookup on keys that are not necessarily in alphabetical order e.g.

```
=if(len(C2) > 0, VLOOKUP(C2,Inventory!$A$2:$E$1000,3,false), "")
```

If you omit False, the lookup assumes that the Inventory keys are in alphabetical order and gives unpredictable results if they aren't. That is why you either get wrong results or no match.

[See](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en-GB)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom - I thought that I had read that FALSE was the default.  I misread that, they just suggested using FALSE.  If that is the suggestion, why isn't it the default?  Boggles the mind :D  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! I suppose in making True the default they are trying to give a nudge towards doing the lookup on sorted data. Being a binary search, it is much more efficient, but it does seem a rather dangerous default to have and for moderate amounts of data the speed isn't that much of an issue..